# for AJAX implementation : please suggest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

which one should use i have following options available

1. ASP.NET ajax with its ajax control
   toolkit controls
2. ASP.NET     ajax with jQuery
3. Ajax Pro http://www.ajaxpro.info/

Please suggest which one to use keeping in mind performance and page size.

Please if any one can shed some light on pros and cons of each of the above

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A month ago I would have chosen Ajax Control toolkit but after spending time behind the scenes with JQuery it will have my personal vote. Especially if using MVC,  however I am having great success refactoring a older Ajax websites developed in Framework 2.0.

JQuery offers a lot more then the Ajax control toolkit and it allows more flexibility, definitly something we will see more of in the future if you follow the commitment Microsoft has made into it.

Comment: i don't think so! Ajax is a great toolkit. it's just the right way it should be used. people often abandon it, because they don't have the patience to learn it.

Comment: I do agree to an extend. I have developed an array of site using the Toolkit and was hard set against not going the JQuery route, I have to admit however there is some things in JQuery which is a lot more complicated in Ajax. Also if your only using the toolkit controls and not learning how to use Ajax without Update Panels, the value in JQuery won't ever be noticed. Also keep in mind that JQuery plugs in to Ajax seamlessly in VS 2008 and in MVC. A lot of SO's magic is done with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

for performance + page size, Asp.net MVC + jQuery is the best. But from your option, I think #1 page size can be reduced by g-zip. Personally, I like Ajax control toolkit because it's easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever you use, just avoid using anything that post all the form values. Update Panels is one of those.

That means:

1. Extenders with the ajax control
   toolkit. These imposes limitations
   on your code.
2. JQuery + JSON. Simple service calls. Leverage the same skills for client side as in other platforms.
3. Ajax Pro. Don't know, so can't say anything about its strengths/weaknesses.

I would stick with JQuery. It works great, and you get skills that work in other platforms :).